Does maximal contact hypersurface (m.c.h.) exist for any curve over a field of arbitrary characteristic, and if so, for what definition of m.c.h.?
Does a maximal contact hypersurface always exist for any curve over a field of arbitrary characteristic, and if so, for what definition of maximal contact hypersurface?
